# Spotlights on paper from reflections inside a sheet of glass

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I placed a sheet of glass (8 mm thick) upon opaque, non-glossy paperboard. The paperboard has a pinhole with a bright light source behind it.

[image: arrangement drawing]

Here's a photo as well:

[image: arrangement photo]

And here's what it looks like if you don't look straight down:

[image: photo of the experiment]

As you can see, there's 28-mm wide spot of more or less uniform brightness. Also, not visible in this photo, there's much dimmer and larger (56 mm) spot with the same sharp boundary. The brightest spot, which is less than 10 mm, has maxed out on camera and actually looks more like a glowing ring around the light source. Below is the output of 3D raytracing renderer, to give you an idea of what that ring looks like:

[image: Concentric spotlights formed by internal reflections inside the glass screen]

Thickness of the glass and size of 28-mm spot suggests that the effect is related to the phenomenon of total internal reflection, though I fail to understand how exactly. Is there a model for these spotlights, which is simpler than doing the raytracing with Fresnel equations?

Comment: Where the *two concentric spotlights* coloured in any way?

Comment: @Farcher they looked white. If there were any rainbows, I didn't notice them.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce the effect that you see.  Is it possible fro you to provide a drawing of the arrangement and what you have observed?

Comment: @Farcher I made a better pinhole, so I could actually make a photo. Also, found mistake in my previous measurements. Updated the post.